# Where did I go wrong? differential equation modeling ion channels

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

[This is the work](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/65052/22020) in question.. specifically when I back subsitute $O$ for $y$, I made a mistake in how I handle $k_{1}$, however, it still needs to come out with the form $O = O_{o} \: e^{-t/\tau}$, which is the exponential decay function. **This step can be seen in the section where I'm deriving $\tau$, about 3/4's the way down, in bold and caps.**

If I just subtract $k_{1}$ then it won't get the correct form, but that's all I'm seeing that can be done to isolate $y$. Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here's the same work as what's from the link:

## To derive $\tau = \frac{1}{k_{1} + k_{-1}}$

Again, we start with the differential equation, but this time we'll integrate. For ease of notation, we'll first make the substitutions $O = y$ and $\frac{\mathrm{dO}}{\mathrm{d} t} = y'$.

Beginning with an intermediate step from the previous section,

$$\frac{\mathrm{dO} }{\mathrm{d} t} = k_{1} - O(k_{1} + k_{-1})$$

$$y' = k_{1} - y(k_{1} + k_{-1})$$

and now applying separation of variables,

$$\frac{y'}{k_{1} - y(k_{1} + k_{-1})} = 1$$

We then use $u$-substitution to integrate the L.H.S. of the equation, where 
$u = k_{1} - y(k_{1} + k_{-1})$ and $u' = -y'(k_{1} + k_{-1})$, which yields

$$ \int \frac{y'}{k_{1} - y(k_{1} + k_{-1})} = \int 1$$

$$-\frac{1}{k_{1} + k_{-1}} \: \int \frac{u'}{u} = \int 1$$

$$-\frac{ln|u|}{k_{1} + k_{-1}} = t$$

Solving for $u$, we have

$$- \: \frac{ln|u|}{k_{1} + k_{-1}} = t$$

$$ln|u| = \: - \: t(k_{1} + k_{-1})$$

$$u =  exp\begin{Bmatrix} - t \: (k_{1} + k_{-1}) \end{Bmatrix}$$
**which is the same as** ***(HERE)***
$$k_{1} - y(k_{1} + k_{-1}) =exp \begin{Bmatrix} - t \: (k_{1} + k_{-1}) \end{Bmatrix}$$

**Now, solving for $y$ and back-substituting $O$ for $y$**, ***(AND HERE)***

$$O = \frac{k_{1}}{k_{1} + k_{-1}} \: \: exp \begin{Bmatrix} - t \: (k_{1} + k_{-1}) \end{Bmatrix}$$

and noticing that $\frac{k_{1}}{k_{1} + k_{-1}} = O_{inf}$ we have

$$O = O_{inf} \: \: exp \begin{Bmatrix} - t \: (k_{1} + k_{-1}) \end{Bmatrix}$$

Lastly, we re-express the exponential argument as

$$- t \: (k_{1} + k_{-1}) = \frac{-t}{\frac{1}{k_{1} + k_{-1}}}$$

where $\tau = \frac{1}{k_{1} + k_{-1}},$ to then get

$$O = O_{inf} \: \: e^{-t/\tau}$$

which fits the form of the exponential decay equation, $N(t) = N_{0} \: e^{-t/\tau}$, where $N = O$ and $N_{0} = O_{inf}$, and $\tau$ is defined to be the average length of time that an ion remains unchanged by the conductance state of an ion channel at a given time $t$.

Comment: Doesnt $$\frac{dO}{dt}=k_1-O(k_1+k_{-1})$$ define a first order dif' thats solvable via integrating factor rather then seperation? With factor $$e^{(k_{1}+k_{-1})t$$? As its of the form. f(t)y'+g(t)y=h(t) ?

Comment: @Vaas Hmm, I'm not sure. Possibly.. let me try that and see what happens.

Comment: @Vaas I'm not having any luck with that method.. I mean, I get an answer of $O = \frac{k_{1}}{k_{1} + k_{-1}}$, but that's what I was getting when I set $O' = 0$, so I'm not sure what's going on..

Comment: You should be worried to reach a solution of the form $$O(t)=ce^{at}$$ for a differential equation of the form $$O'(t)=aO(t)+b$$ with $b\ne0$ since the function you suggest does not solve the differential equation. Furthermore, the solution $O(t)$ you suggest does not fit the initial condition $$O(0)=O_o$$ in general. These two remarks might suggest that the step where you solve $$u'=au$$ by $$u(t)=e^{at}$$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I have zero knowledge of ion channels. So if this makes no sense, my apologies.

That being said, after a couple minutes of Googling the subject, I believe the following holds:

1.) if $O(t)$ denotes the probability of finding an open channel when the channel opened at time $0$ (again, no idea what this means), then $O(0) = 1$;

2.) rather than $O(t) = O_{inf}e^{-t/\tau}$, it looks like the form of this function should be
$$O(t)= O_{inf} + (O_0-O_{inf})e^{-t/\tau},$$
where $O_0=O(0)$, and $O_{inf} = \lim \limits_{t \to \infty} O(t)$.

(citing these two sources: [Ionic Channels in Cells and Model Systems](https://books.google.com/books?id=QZjlBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&dq=ionic+channels+in+cells+and+model+systems+exponential+decay&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR4IDc2eXVAhWE5CYKHSYbDwAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=ionic%20channels%20in%20cells%20and%20model%20systems%20exponential%20decay&f=false) , [Ion Channels and Electrical Signaling](https://dasher.wustl.edu/bio5357/reading/ion-channels-11.pdf) )

Given these two assumptions, I believe the misstep you've made is that you antidifferentiated without adding a constant; that is, you've integrated without regard to initial conditions.

When you have 
$$ -\frac{1}{k_1+k_{-1}}\int \frac{u'}{u} = \int 1$$
this is not exactly correct. Since we are integrating from  time $0$ up through some time $t$, we must accommodate appropriately:

$$ -\frac{1}{k_1+k_{-1}}\int_{u(0)}^{u(t)} \frac{u'}{u} = \int_{0}^{t} 1$$

If you continue from here, you should be able to end up with the form I have mentioned above.

Hope this helps!